# Extremely high memory usage in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, zip

I am having a hard time solving this memory usage problem

**A brief explanation of goals:**

To create a zip of many files and save it on S3

**Info and steps taken:**

The files are images, and will range from 10-50mb in size, and there will be thousands.

I have adjusted Lambda to have 3GB of memory, and I was hoping for a 2.5-3GB of files per zip.

**The Problem:**

Currently, I have a test file which is exactly 1GB. The problem is, the memory Lambda reports using is about 2085. I understand that there would be overhead, but why 2GB?

**Stretch Goal:**

To be able to create a zip larger than 3GB

**Tests and results:**

If I comment out the in_memory.seek(0) and the Object.Put to S3, the memory doubling does not happen (but, no file is created either...)

**Current code:**

```
bucket = 'dev'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
list = [
    "test/3g/file1"
]
list_index = 1


# Setup a memory store for streaming into a zip file
in_memory = BytesIO()

# Initiate zip file with "append" settings
zf = ZipFile(in_memory, mode="a")

# Iterate over contents in S3 bucket with prefix, filtering empty keys
for key in list:
    object = s3.Object(bucket, key).get()

    # Grab the filename without the key to create a "flat" zip file
    filename = key.split('/')[-1]

    # Stream the body of each key into the zip
    zf.writestr(filename, object['Body'].read())

# Close the zip file
zf.close()

# Go to beginning of memory store
in_memory.seek(0)

# Stream zip file to S3
object = s3.Object('dev', 'test/export-3G-' + str(list_index) + '.zip')
object.put(Body=in_memory.read())
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with Python, but, could it be the case that zip file is not being compressed and all the content of in_memory is copied as is into zf + some overhead?

Comment: The curious thing is that if I remove the in_memory.seek(0) and the Object.put onto S3 the memory doesn't double.

Comment: Iirc body accepts any seekable file-like object, so you shouldn't need to call read on the last line, just use `object.put(Body=in_memory)`. I believe that is what is doubling your data.